# how to monitor stucked applications in yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

How can I track stuck applications in Yarn?
[image: 4 example]

I have apps that have been running for over a week and would like to track them?
Perhaps there is some simple way to do this?

JMX? Api cloudera?

I did not find any ways other than writing scripts.
Help!

Comment: An entire `4.3s` of CPU time in a week? That's not good.

Comment: this pic is just example. 
My question about monitoring stucked applications in yarn:)

Comment: You can use the YARN UI directly